# How to integrate PayPal with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new in Zend Framework and i need to integrate paypal. I don't know how to integrate 
PayPal with Zend Framework. Any URL or sample code will be good for us.

Please Help...

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This would maybe be a good place to start](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Service_PayPal+-+A.J.+Brown)

[Choosing the Right PayPal Solution](http://devzone.zend.com/article/12)

[Integrating PayPal IPN with Zend Framework](http://www.zendcasts.com/forum/topic/168/integrating-paypal-ipn-with-zend-framework/)

Good luck

Comment: you should accept (green tick) answers that help you, Manoj ;)

Answer (score 7):

I recommend this [payum module](https://github.com/Payum/PayumModule) for those who looking for a **paypal + zend2** integration solution. It not only supports paypal but other [+35 payments](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/supported-payments-and-other-libraries.md) as well.

It contains lots of features ready to be used. To mention some: easy configuration, secured capture controller.

Answer (score 2):

Dude, if those links get too complex, or you just want to use the NVP API instead of SOAP, try my two-part tutorial about leveraging the [Zend Framework to use the PayPal Express Checkout and PayPal Payments Pro API](http://www.alexventure.com/2011/02/28/zend-framework-and-the-paypal-api-part-1-of-2/).

Comment: ...ah nuts... My site's down. I'm transfering my domain from siteground to godaddy. Guess only the google cache version is available until I get my nameservers up to date again (may take another day or two)... Sorry about that folks.

Comment: ...And we're back. Site is back up. :-) Enjoy

Comment: @Alex don't know if you will read that. But I am confused in your tutorial with what you call Paypal_Adapter in part2. Is that the Paypal_Client from part one?

Comment: @Iznogood Yes, that is the same class. Thank you for pointing it out, I will fix that immediately.