# Paypal integration with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal

I was wondering how to integrate PayPal with Zend Framework?

I am going to build a little in-app market with about 5-15(+10 optional) products for which I am going to store information in the database.

However I wanted the user to see the information about the products and when he clicks the "buy" button to enter the quantity and then to be redirected directly to PayPal(I know this is a regular process and I can implement it with normal PHP code) I am thinking to use the html way, but I know it is not secure enough as far as I can think of it(because user can modify HTML with developer console or in any other way.) So my actual question is:

How can I send the data to my own controller which gets the user filled quantity and item code and the generates all the information to be presented to PayPal for further processing?

PS: Please no downvotes, I am kind of new to ZF
Info: ZF 1.12

Comment: Read Paypal docs and you will understand the process. User sends the data to your server, your server checks every field corresponds to the data in your database and then you post it to Paypal.

Comment: duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390709/how-to-integrate-paypal-with-zend-framework)

Comment: You can build functions to interact with the PayPal API directly from your Zend controllers.  I've got a [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) you might be interested.  I know lots of people are currently using it with Zend.